# Querying for date range in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, timezone

I have a scope that queries for today's calls.  Based off of the scope I use it to count the amount of calls for today.

My dates are stored in UTC but rails converts to my local timezone.  What I'm trying to do is find all calls between today at 00:00 and 23:59.

Scope:

```
scope :today, where("DATE(transfer_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.utc.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.utc.end_of_day)
```

irb output: (The call it catches due to UTC)

```
irb(main):010:0> Call.last.transfer_date
  Call Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls" ORDER BY "calls"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> Sun, 07 Oct 2012 19:45:00 CDT -05:00
irb(main):011:0> 

irb(main):011:0> Call.last.transfer_date.utc
  Call Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls" ORDER BY "calls"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> 2012-10-08 00:45:00 UTC
```

I'm trying to figure out how to query only calls that were between 00:00 and 23:59 for today.  So far trying to scope with and without utc, zone, etc doesn't work.  It keeps pulling the scope based off of UTC which includes the call from yesterday (yesterday if it's formatted with the local timezone).

How can I query between the two times to get the correct output?  I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: can you please make your questions clear please, means which model you gave scope, and at bottom you didn't wrote today as scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to compensate for UTC by rewriting my scope as follows:

```
scope :today, where("transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use an exclusive range.

```
scope :today, where(:transfer_date => Date.today...Date.tomorrow)
```

Comment: `A..B` will trigger `BETWEEN` in SQL which is inclusive (includes range boundary values A, B)
`SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls" WHERE "calls"."transfer_date" BETWEEN $1 AND $2`.  \
  
A..B will trigger something like: `transfer_rate >= today AND transfer_rate <= tomorrow` again inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is overkill, but I would suggest using a helper method for getting the time range and then querying the db. Something like

```
# Gets time range for x number timeunits ago
  def time_range(unit, timeunit = nil)
    if timeunit == "weeks"
      now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week
    elsif timeunit == "months"
      now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month
    else
      now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
    end
    # Ex: time_range(0, "days") --> Get the time range for today  between the beginning of today and the beginning of tommorow - 1 second
    now - unit.send(timeunit)..now + 1.send(timeunit) - 1.seconds - unit.send(timeunit)
  end
```

will help you to request time ranges. So when you request something like;

```
time_range(0, "days")
```

it will return the time range for 0 days ago (today);

```
Wed, 07 Sep 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00..Wed, 07 Sep 2016 23:59:59 UTC +00:00
```

And then you can simply query the database object and count everything within the range with;

```
Calls.where(transfer_date: time_range(unit, timeunit)).count
```

Comment: This is good, and thanks for the example, but I ended up going with a simple lambda scope a few years back :)